# Which color profile is appropriate for images being printed on canvas?

Tags: print-design, color-profile, save, document-setup, configuration

I want to know the best colour space settings for preparing an image for canvas printing.

The research I've done mostly speaks about sRGB and some speak about Adobe RGB. I'm not sure what to do.

What is the best colour setting and how do I set up the colour space in Adobe Photoshop? (CS3)

What should I be aware of when deciding which color profile to choose during save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer: ask your printer.

Some printers have workflows that allow and actually encourage using an RGB colorspace for art files. Others prefer CMYK. Check with the printer and find out what works best. Some will even provide you with a color model to use in your design programs for soft-proofing.

Comment: Technically I am the printer. Its something i know little about but want to start it up. The printer i have access to manages RGB very well. Its a Roland VP540.

Comment: You might be best off checking with Roland for color models and best practices for color profiling. See [this support document](http://support.rolanddga.com/docs/Documents/departments/Technical%20Services/Manuals%20and%20Guides/VersaWorks_Profiling.pdf) for how to go about creating a color profile for the printer which can be used on your computer for soft-proofing.