# How can we see the real "Near-Cyan"

Tags: color, color-theory, color-reproduction

On my computer screen and your computer screen lies a "Near-Cyan" rectangle (100,250,255).
Considering the number of hardware buttons on my computer and your computer and the number of software buttons on my computer and your computer we probably dont see the same color. 
My question: how do I get and distribute the "real", "standard" and "correct" "Near-Cyan"?

Comment: Related: [What should I do regarding color profile when designing for the web?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/9208/23061), [What are Color Profiles?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/114/23061), and [Which color profile is appropriate for images being printed on canvas?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/45864/23061)

Answer (score 1):

This is what color profiles, and color management is for. You profile your monitor, with a colorimeter, you can then  convert that color to a device neutral scale such as Lab, or standard scale rgb like sRGB.

A person with a appropriately profiled or calibrated (I suggest you calibrate your monitor to sRGB regularily*) monitor can then convert that color to closest possible color on her/his monitor using the color management engine of their OS/browser/imaging/authoring application. So image on my monitor is quite close to image on my work monitor, and any other calibrated / profiled system when possible. Because I am working in a calibrated environment that I test regularily

A person with a nonprofiled/calibrated monitor will just see random color. The best you can hope then is that they would be somewhere near sRGB. But that is more guessing than anything else.

* if you really want to be pedantic of color then you do this continiously as the light conditions at your desk affects how you precieve color.